# Regularizing kernel and mollifier

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, regularity-theory-of-pdes, optimal-transport

I am learning the book "Optimal transport old and new" by Villani.

We have the following notion of Regularizing kernels.

[image]

My first question is: if this regularizing kernel is similar to [mollifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20mollifiers%20(also%20known,generalized)%20functions%2C%20via%20convolution.). Specifically, I think if we let $\mathcal{Y}=\{0\}$, $\phi=K_1(x,0)$ and $\phi_\epsilon=\epsilon^{-d}\phi(x/\epsilon)$, then the $\phi$ is indeed a mollifier.

[image]

My second question is: if we construct a mollifier like I described above, then is this $K_\epsilon\mu$ the mollification of $\mu$?

My third question is about this property: if $\mu$ is a finite measure supported in $\mathcal{Y}$, then $(K_\epsilon\mu)\nu$ converges to $\mu$ in duality with $\mathcal{C}_b(X)$. But if we let $\mathcal{Y}=\{0\}$, this $\mu$ can only be a Dirac measure on $0$. Is this convergence property true for measure $\mu$ without compact support?

Thank you!